# jQuery resizable: how to resize hover the container td?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, calendar, jquery-ui-resizable

I have a table that is like a calendar.
Please have a look at the code snippet, it is hard to explain what I want to get from jQuery.

I can drop a block named "test" into a resource `<td>` but when i want to resize it he resize his resource container td...

i just want to resize my dropped "test" block hover the td's and i don't know how to do that...

actually the div test change the size of the td...

thanks by advance for your help

```js
        $(function () {

            // There's the gallery and the trash
            var $job = $("#testblocks"),
                $ressource = $(".ressource");

            // Let the gallery items be draggable
            $("div", $job).draggable({
                cancel: "a.ui-icon", // clicking an icon won't initiate dragging
                revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
                containment: ".containment-wrapper",
                helper: "clone",
                cursor: "move",
                snap: "td",
                scroll: false,
                refreshPositions: true,
                drag: function () {
                    var offset = $(this).offset();
                    var xPos = offset.left;
                    var yPos = offset.top;
                    /*$('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
                    $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);*/
                }
            });
            $("div", $job).resizable({
                handles: 'e, w',
                containment: ".containment-wrapper"
            });

            $ressource.droppable({
                hoverClass: 'hovering',
                tolerance: 'pointer',
                accept: "#testblocks > div, .ressource div",
                classes: {
                    "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-highlight"
                },
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    $(ui.draggable).appendTo($(this, "td"));
                }
            });

            $job.droppable({
                accept: ".ressource div",
                classes: {
                    "ui-droppable-active": "custom-state-active"
                },
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    $(ui.draggable).appendTo($job);
                }
            });


        });
```

```css
        
        .drag {
            height: 49px;
            width: 60px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            /*height:50px;*/
            width: 160px;
        }

        th {
            border: 1px solid black;
            /*height:50px;*/
            width: 180px;
        }

        tr {
            border: 1px solid black;
            height: 150px;
        }

        .basr {
            height: 150px;

        }

        .masterContent {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table cellspacing="0" style="border:1px solid black; text-align:center;">
    <tr style="border:1px solid black;">
        <th style="border:1px solid black;"></th>
        <th style="border:1px solid black;">12am</th>
        <th style="border:1px solid black;">1am</th>
        <th style="border:1px solid black;">2am</th>
        <th style="border:1px solid black;">3am</th>
        <th style="border:1px solid black;">4am</th>
        <th style="border:1px solid black;">5am</th>
        <th style="border:1px solid black;">6am</th>
        <th style="border:1px solid black;">7am</th>
        <th style="border:1px solid black;">8am</th>
        <th style="border:1px solid black;">9am</th>
        <th style="border:1px solid black;">10am</th>
        <th style="border:1px solid black;">11am</th>
        <th style="border:1px solid black;">12pm</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="border:1px solid black;">
    <tr>
        <th>Ressource 1</th>
        <td colspan="26" rowspan="4" class="masterContent">
            <table cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;" class="containment-wrapper">
                <tr>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                    <td class="ressource"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="basr">
                    <td colspan="26" id="testblocks">
                        <!--<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
                            <div id="posX">blob</div>
                            <div id="posY">blob</div>
                        </div>-->
                        <div class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr drag">
                            test
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Ressource 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="basr">
        <th>bac à sable</th>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: As you're appending the item into the Cell, this is the expected behavior. Consider adjusting the Overflow in CSS so that the boundaries of the DIV can overflow the boundaries of the container.

Comment: okay you true i change html thanks